# Is there an audible difference in HDD vs SSD, better sound quality?

Tags: ssd

Is there an audible difference (sound quality) between HDD and SSD storage devices? I am considering both options but I desire the best fidelity.

Comment: No​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: This question has nothing to do with sound really. You need to study more. just go on the net. Vote to close. :)

Comment: Various of us are interpretting your question differently.  Can you clarify whether you are referring to reproduction of the audio data stored on the drive vs. mechanical noise produced by operation of the hardware?

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no difference. Because they are both digital storage devices, they reproduce any data bit-for-bit. There is no difference in audio quality for the same files stored on HDD, SSD, SD Card, CD etc. Read speeds do not come into play because of the low bit rates involved in even 96 kHz/24bit (very high quality) music.

Comment: This covers "normal" operation.  What about the situation where heavy use is being made of a swap file (could be from some other process independent of the audio).  Might faster data rates of an SSD reduce the potential impact (which could present as breaks/lags, etc. in the sound)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an audiophile, and indeed seriously question the purported listening abilities of audiophiles; that said, I believe that the audio quality of an SSD will, in some cases be **marginally/theoretically** better - for the following reasons:

1. Hard drives are spinning parts and therefore make a noise.  This is noticeable, and is a known factor in building Home Theatre PC Cases, where they try and do things to dampen that sound.  That sound includes the sound of the drive itself
   and case rattle caused by the spinning parts.
2. Power Usage.  A typical hard drive consumes about 4-10 watts more power than an SSD.  This needs to be dissipated. 10 watts is not much, but it still adds to the cooling load on the system, which means a small chance of needing larger fans or an incresed fan RPM.
3. Increased noise on the power rail. The power draw characteristics of a hard drive are such that they will add to the noise on a power rail. This could translate to noise on the audio output of the system.

Other posters are correct in their assertions that both devices are digital, so don't directly impact on the quality of the audio - if the storage component was isolated, totally silenced and only the bits it produced fed into a player there would be no difference - but the drive does not exist in isolation.

On the flip side, the SSD / HDD is not a significant source of noise compared to the CPU and other components in a device.

That said, the effect will be more noticeable then a [$10k monster ethernet cable](http://hothardware.com/news/10000-ethernet-cable-claims-earth-shattering-advancement-in-audio-fidelity-if-youre-stupid-enough-to-buy-it) (which is, in case you think I'm that naive, a laughable scam)

That said, you may be better off looking at the *NON AUDIOPHILE* properties of the devices to make your decision, as they are almost certainly way more relevant.  The advantages and disadvantages of each are:

SSD: Low failure rate, high speed.  (High speed will likely not matter if it's only audio you are storing.  If it's the whole operating system the boot up times and responsiveness will be much faster).   The failure rate is about 1/10th that of a hard drive, although most failures are catastrophic, ie no warning and low probability of recovery of lost data.

HDD: If you have lots of data this is a way more cost effective way of storing it.  When the drive fails - and all drives fail eventually - there is a decent chance you will still be able to recover your data.

Comment: If I read the question correctly, it's about the audio data, not sound produced by operation of the hardware.

Comment: @fixer1234 I disagree. I think he's talking about the sound that the drives produce.